# Applying CSS transform to element with display:block, adds lots of scroll to the page

Tags: css, scroll, transform, block

I've got a design in which the navigation is tilted 10 degrees. It's built using an unordered list and css graphic elements as backgrounds on 'a' classes and display:block to show the whole graphic. Like y'do.

Pretty standard, except when I add the transform to the unordered list, the page scrolls about 1000px or more beyond the end of the page. I've tried adding the transform to the a links, to the list item, all with the same result of page scroll.  Visually, transforming the unordered list is what I want to do. Other than the extended scroll, it looks awesome and works as intended.

(Without the display block or when using straight text, the transform works without issue and no extended scroll is added.)

Any ideas for keeping the page scroll from going haywire like that?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show an example? (jsfiddle.net) Also, consider overflow:hidden on a wrapping element to prevent the scrolling.

Comment: Resolved! 

I added overflow:auto; to the unordered list. Thanks to my friend, Lawrie!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow:auto;` to the list element in your CSS, and the scroll insanity should (fingers crossed) sort itself out.